# Python replace mention of a variable in string with actual variable

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
s="b a[1] something funny"
```

and I have these variables

```
b="10"
a=["1","is"]
```

is it possible for me to somehow replace values in the first string with values from my variables, hopefully with one function. I don't want to execute the string with eval because it contains invalid Python code.

Comment: You should try to turn your string into anything suitable for .format() method

Comment: Please correct the name of your variables, there is two `s`.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice. Corrected mistake.

Comment: Can't test right now but I suposse `.format()` would help : `s = "{} {} something funny".format(b,s[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            s="b sx[1] something funny"
            b="10"
            sx=["1","is"]
            map = {}
            for i in range(0,len(sx)):
                map["sx["+str(i)+"]"]=sx[i]
            map['b'] = b
            lis = s.split(" ")
            ans = []
            for i in range(0,len(lis)):
                try:
                    ans.append(map[lis[i]])
                except Exception, e:
                    ans.append(lis[i])
            ans = " ".join(ans)
            print ans
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use this kind of formatting:

```
s = '{b} {a} something funny'.format(b="10", a=["1","is"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without defining values for variables in .format() function?

Comment: Yes ! just define the variables before that call.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what you are trying ? ( Multiple edits not overwriting the original version so it can serve as a tracking point )

Answer (score 1):

That does the work, at least on your example:

```
b="10"
a=["1","is"]

def protectedEval(mystr):
    ret = []                       
    for i in mystr.split():
        try:
            ret.append(eval(i))
        except NameError:
            ret.append(i)
    return ' '.join(ret)

protectedEval("b a[1] something funny")
```

But you probably should use either .format or %.

Answer (score 0):

In yet to be released Python 3.6 you can use [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). For example:

```
>>> b = "10"
>>> a = ["1", "is"]
>>> s = f"{b} {a[1]} something funny"
>>> print(s)
10 is something funny
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could turn your string template into a 'formattable' one, this should work:

```
s="{b} {a[1]} something funny"
b="10"
a=["1","is"]
print s.format(**locals())

10 is something funny
```

Although you should avoid `locals()` in favour of an esplicit dictionary:

```
s="{b} {a[1]} something funny"
parms = dict(
             b="10",
             a=["1","is"]
            )
print s.format(**parms)

10 is something funny
```